# Why does Unix background process termination line not print right after termination?

Tags: shell, background-process

So as an example if I run:

`sleep 1 & sleep 2 & sleep 3`

I will immediately get the process IDs e.g.

```
[1] ...
[2] ...
```

and then the shell freezes until the `sleep 3` finishes running and then prints these at the same time:

```
[1]-  Done                    sleep 1
[2]+  Done                    sleep 2
```

just wondering what the underlying implementation is that leads to this behavior.

Comment: Are you asking for the technicalities of the _implementation_, or for the _reasons_ for that behaviour? Did you expect some other behaviour then the one you saw? Do note also that you're running `sleep 3` in the foreground, and only the other two in the background. If you weren't, the behaviour would also depend on the shell (e.g. zsh is different from Bash there), but based on the output you seem to be running Bash.

Comment: @ilkkachu Yea I'm just wondering what the underlying implementation is. Is the child process printing the termination line? why is it not outputted until the sleep 3 is finished?

Comment: This behaviour is part of Bash job control, and can be modified. If you `set -b` in Bash before running this command, the jobs will be reported as `Done` without waiting for the next opportunity at a prompt. Mix it up like `sleep 15 & sleep 5 & sleep 10 &`. However, you get the prompt as soon as all the jobs start: you will *not* get a further prompt after they have all completed, until you hit Enter again.

Answer (score 0):

The waiting of the shell is caused by the last `sleep` that is not backgrounded.

The messages

```
[1]-  Done                    sleep 1
[2]+  Done                    sleep 2
```

are in general printed at a convenient time, mostly when there is a prompt. Try

```
sleep 3 &
```

and count to 10. No output is generated. But when you hit the enter, you get a new prompt and before that, you'll get the `Done` message.

This is the same as what you are experiencing.

Comment: Note that the "`sleep 3&` and count to 10" behavior differs between shells. If you're using `bash`, you'll see the behavior that Ljm describes here.

Comment: I could get a similar behavior using forking and periodically checking if the child processes have finished their job, in this implementation, the parent process takes in user "shell prompt" in an infinite while loop. First I tried handling SIGCHLD and that prints as soon as the background child process has terminated, but then I tried checking if the background child processes have finished their work after each iteration of the while loop. And that gave me exact behavior to the bash terminal